# Round number down to nearest power of ten

Tags: javascript

I have a number and I need to round it down to the nearest power of ten. It seems like this should be possible without a whole bunch of if statements or using recursion or looping, but I don't know the most elegant way to do it. In case it's unclear what I mean, here are some examples:

```
f(1) === 1
f(5) === 1
f(15) === 10
f(43) === 10
f(456) === 100
f(999) === 100
```

To clarify: I do not need nearest multiple of 10 (not: 10, 20, 30...), but nearest power of ten (10, 100, 1000...).

Edit: To my knowledge this is not a duplicate question. Please stop closing as a duplicate of a question asking about rounding to the nearest *multiple* of ten. This question is unrelated to the linked question, because it asks about rounding to the nearest *power* of ten. If you would like to close this question as a duplicate, please find and link a duplicate question. The question which is currently linked was commented about 30 seconds after I posted the question, by someone who did not read the entire question and merely commented complaining about it being a duplicate. That person has since deleted his comments (after realizing he was wrong), although you can see comments by myself and someone else both pointing out that this is not a duplicate.

Comment: @Dale_dale12 No, those are not powers of 10.

Comment: I need powers of 10 (1, 10, 100, etc), not multiples of ten.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply get the length of the number(by converting Number into a string) and then generate the result by taking the power of `10`(where the exponent is `length - 1`).

```
function generateNum(v) {
  return Math.pow(10, v.toString().length - 1);
}
```

```js
var data = [1, 5, 15, 43, 456, 456, 999];


data.forEach(function(v) {
  console.log(generateNum(v));
})

function generateNum(v) {
  return Math.pow(10, v.toString().length - 1);
}
```

---

**FYI :** In case number includes decimal part then you need to avoid decimal part by taking the floor value.

```
function generateNum(v) {
  return Math.pow(10, Math.floor(v).toString().length - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 20):

You could take the logarithm of 10 and take the integer value for the power of 10.

```js
function f(v) {
    return Math.pow(10, Math.floor(Math.log10(v)));
}

console.log(f(1));   //   1
console.log(f(5));   //   1
console.log(f(15));  //  10
console.log(f(43));  //  10
console.log(f(456)); // 100
console.log(f(999)); // 100
```

Comment: fails for f(531), expected 1000 got 100, use Math.round() instead of Math.floor()

Comment: @marvel308, but op is asking for `999` the value of `100`, not `1000` or do i miss something?

Comment: This answer works. I want to round down to a power of ten. My question title wasn't super clear.

Comment: using @marvel308 suggestion to use Math.round() did get me closer to what I wanted, but one gotchya was f(316) == 100; and f(317) == 1000; Still works for a majority of my use cases so I'm going to use it, just something to be aware of.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a variant that works for negative numbers:

```
let round10 = v => Math.pow(10, Math.floor(Math.log10(Math.abs(v)))) * Math.pow(-1, v < 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the following way

```js
function f(num){
    let count = 0;
    while(num > 1){
        count ++;
        num/= 10;
    }
    return Math.pow(10, count-1) * (Math.round(num) ? 10: 1);
}

console.log(f(453));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
f = n => +("1"+"0".repeat((""+n).length-1));
```

or:

```
f = n => +(""+n).split("").map((_,i)=>i?"0": "1").join("");
```